# Svelte reactive statement which updates when only some of the referenced variables are changed

Tags: svelte

I have been using Svelte for a while and this issue really bugs me.
How could I create a reactive statement which updates when only some of the referenced variables are changed?

For example, I want to re-compute `d` only when `a` or `b` are changed, but not when `c` is changed:

```html
<script>
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let c = 3;
    $: d = a + b + c;
</script>
```

But `d` is re-eveluated when `a`,`b`, or `c` changes.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use function that accepts `a` and `b` and closes over `c`:

```
function update(a, b) {
  return a + b + c;
}

$: d = update(a, b);
```

Comment: Brilliant I wish the official docs referenced this